# How can I call a custom function in "onFilter" in ant design?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I would like to call a custom function in "onFilter" property given by ant design on columns. I can go for the custom filter dropdown as an option but I would like to use the default filter option given by ant design. i.e

```
{
  title: 'Address',
  dataIndex: 'address',
  key: 'address',
  filters: [{
    text: 'London',
    value: 'London',
  }, {
    text: 'New York',
    value: 'New York',
  }],
  onFilter: (value, record) => record.address.indexOf(value) === 0,
}
```

But the only thing I need to change here is a custom function (that will trigger the api call and set the new data in the redux state so the component will re render it self) something like

```
{
  ...
  onFilter: (value, record) => this.getFilteredData(value),
}
```

But when I do this I get this error which does make sense too.

> Warning: setState(…): Cannot update during an existing state
> transition

So kindly guide me on how to do that as I am new to react and ant design both.

Answer (score 1):

Dispatching an action inside onFilter is probably not a good idea because it will be called a couple of times on each filter change

But you can edit your reducer to set `filterLoading` to `true` when this action `getFilteredData` is called and the new onFilter can be like this

```
  ...
  onFilter: (value) => {
    if(! this.props.filterLoading) {
      this.getFilteredData(value);
    }
    return true;
  }
```

A couple of things to consider

- You have to pass `filterLoading` to the component
- Don't forget to set `filterLoading` to false on `GET_FILTERED_DATA_SUCCESS` action is called

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried it but having the same problem. i.e Once reducer sets the state, its getting called again and again. And as a result, the same warning which I mentioned earlier. Other thing I can do is to implement the custom filter of ant design. But that means, I have to set the hide and show etc for each column's filter manually which I don't want to. Plus the design on the little popover as well.

Comment: I see. You can try to do something ugly like `if(this.currentFilterValue !== value) { this.getFilteredData(value) } this.currentFilterValue = value; return true;` inside `onFilter`